# Read embedded text file as string array (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, file-io, embedded-resource

I'm trying to read an embedded textfile.

The text file has the structure:

```
Word1
Word2
Word3
...
```

I'm trying to get this into a string array, but am unable to do so.

I mean, i've come across this: [How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file) but this only reads the file as a string and while i could read the string, then separate it out line-by-line, there seems like there should be a simpler solution.

Is there?

Comment: Then use `reader.ReadLine()` instead of `reader.ReadToEnd()`

Comment: Using that would require me knowing how many lines the file length is, and i don't think i can find that out from a stream...

Comment: A general tip - Embed only if its needed. Mostly one should link it compile time to resources.

Comment: LordAro Have you heard `List<string>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this extension method for splitting lines:

```
public static string[] GetLines(this string s)
{
    return s.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);
}
```

Then you can do:

```
string[] strings = Properties.Resources.YourResource.GetLines();
```

Comment: I didn't (or haven't yet) bother with the extension method, but that works great, thanks :)

Comment: Might i ask how you actually add that to your solution?  Sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: The method GetLines must be in a static non-generic class. It is called an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx)