# Read resource text file into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files, internal

I have a text file as a resource that I want to read into an array.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] questions = new string[4];
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Properties.Resources.TextFile1);


        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            questions[i] = sr.ReadLine();
        }
        sr.Close();

        for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++)
        {
           textBox1.Text = questions[n];
        }
```

I then attempted the following code but keep getting a Null exception

```
        string[] questions = new string[4];
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        var resourceName = Properties.Resources.TextFile1;

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
```

Comment: Brilliant Steve thanks for being so helpful, maybe a link to provide some support instead of flagging the question. I cant find the an answer that solves my issue.

Comment: Sorry but you talk about a resource file so it seem obvious that you should use the [GetResourceManifestStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(v=vs.110).aspx) not a StreamReader. If this doesn't work could you explain better your question? I will reopen it.

Comment: well its obvious to an experienced user, I am attempting to learn and have exhausted a lot of time on youtube videos and other questions on here and still cant find a solution so in a final attempt I asked a question....

Comment: Did you set the property "Build Action" for the file to "Embedded resource"?, missing that there is no resource data to work with

Comment: yes I have it still comes up with a Null error

Comment: Tried with a simple project. After the call to Properties.Resource.TextFile1 the variable resourceName already contains the contents of a textfile. So you don't need at all the reading from the stream.

Comment: Firstly thank you for taking time to respond to me, secondly Im still lost as to how to fix this.

Comment: Where do you get the null reference exception? If you step through your code, does `Properties.Resources.TextFile` contain the contents of the text file?

Comment: error is at this line

 using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))

  and the text in the file appears when I move my mouse over the properties.resources.Textfile line

Comment: What do you mean by repeating **internal** everywhere?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read embedded text file as string array (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342988/read-embedded-text-file-as-string-array-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Properties.Resources.TextFile1` contains the contents of the file, you don't need to use a `StreamReader` at all. You can just parse the string however you like. In your case you could split the string on the newline character:

```
var questions = Properties.Resources.TextFile1.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and I get an overload message. the best overloaded match has some invalid arguements

Comment: Did you get it working? Was that compile error on the `Split` call? Which arguments were invalid?